# Change scope variable from directive in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am pretty new with Angular and I got the following problem:

I have a list view and a details view with some tags. I created a directive in order to change the route (to list view) and load new elements from a service on the click event.
What I want is that the click event also change a scope variable, so that i can show/hide a button to clear filters in the list view.

Actually I am able to change the variable from the directive, but the button doesn't show/hide with ngIf/ngShow/ngHide when the variable changes.

I tried with `$scope.$apply`, both in the directive and in the controller. I tried calling a `toggle` function from the controller and to change the variable directly inside the directive, but nothing worked.

I tried calling the toggle function from another button and it worked perfectly!

Here is my code:

Here i try to change the variable in the directive and `$apply`:

```
.directive('filterTag', function(getFeed, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'mainController',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                $location.path('/list');
                scope.filtered = true;
                scope.$apply();
                return getFeed.getTagged(this.text);

            });
        }
    }
})
```

This is inside the controller:

```
$scope.filtered = false;
$scope.toggleFiltered = function() {
    $scope.filtered = !$scope.filtered;
}

$scope.$watch('filtered', function() {
    alert('filtered: ' + $scope.filtered);
});
```

I use $watch to be sure the variable changed correctly and it does, both from directive and from toggle button.

Here is the button i want to show/hide if filters are applied (this is in the list view):

```
<button type="button" ng-show="filtered">Clear filter</button>
```

I tried to add this button to check if I was missing something or for syntax errors, but it works perfectly

```
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleFiltered()">toggle filter</button>
```

I looked for answers in the last two days but I couldn't find the solution.
Can't figure out the problem with my code.

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cdbLR24CRssktS5COho?p=preview)

Comment: could you upload your code to Jsfiddle or plunker  to help you?

Comment: here my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/5cdbLR24CRssktS5COho?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to show /hide the 'clear filter' button , or another button ?

Comment: I want to show/hide the clear filter button. I added the other one just to check the toggle function worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can share the 'filtered' between two controllers (different scopes), so you can use `$rootScope` to do that or you can use a `service/factory`  in this way when the 'filtered' is changed in any controller it will change in the other!

Use the $rootScope.filtered instead of $scope.filtered  and you can initialize the $rootScope.filtered in the run() function at the module.